# one hot encoding in Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, circuit, vivado

Im just starting to learn how to code in Verilog. Can anyone help me figure out how to implement the following code in verilog using one-hot encoding

```
module Controller(b, x, clk, rst);
input b, clk, rst;
output x;
reg x;

parameter Off = 2'b00,
          On1 = 2'b01,
          On2 = 2'b10,
          On3 = 2'b11;
reg [1:0] currentstate;
reg [1:0] nextstate;
//state register
always @ (posedge rst or posedge clk)
begin
if(rst==1)
    currentstate <= Off;
else
    currentstate <= nextstate;
end
//combinational 
always @ (*)
begin
    case (currentstate)
        Off: begin
        x <= 0;
        if(b==0)
            nextstate <= Off;
        else
            nextstate <= On1;
        end
        On1 : begin
            x <= 1;
            nextstate <= On2;
        end
        On2 : begin
            x <= 1;
            nextstate <= On3;
        end
        On3 : begin 
            x <= 1;
            nextstate <= Off;
        end
    endcase
end
```

I tried changing the parameters to:

```
parameter Off = 4'b0001,
          On1 = 4'b0010,
          On2 = 4'b0100,
          On3 = 4'b1000;
```

However, ive read that this is not a good implementations.

Comment: And where you read that?

Comment: @prakash Darji http://asics.chuckbenz.com/detailed_one_hot.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the **advantages** of onehot encoding in FSMs are as follows:

> 1. **Low switching activity.** Since only single bit is switched at a time, the power consumption is less and it is less prone to glitches.
> 2. **Simplified encoding.** One can determine the state just by looking at the bit position of '1' in the current state variable.

The **disadvantage** of this technique is that **it requires more number of flops**. So, if one has a FSM with 10 different states, one needs 10 flops, while one needs only 4 flops when using decimal encoding.

Coming to your question, it is simple to change to onehot encoded FSM. One needs to implement a `case` statement based on the *position* of `1` in the `currentstate` variable. The code snippet can be implemented as follows:

```
parameter Off = 2'b00,
          On1 = 2'b01,
          On2 = 2'b10,
          On3 = 2'b11;
//...
always @ (*)
begin
    nextstate = 4'b0000;
    case (1'b1)
        currentstate[Off] : begin
        x = 0;
        if(b==0)
            nextstate[Off] = 1'b1;
        else
            nextstate[On1] = 1'b1;
        end
        currentstate[On1] : begin
            x = 1;
            nextstate[On2] = 1'b1;
        end
//...
```

A simple example is available at [this link](http://asics.chuckbenz.com/OneHotCodingBestPractices.htm) and explanation is [over here](http://only-vlsi.blogspot.in/2008/06/one-hot-encoding.html). [Cummings paper](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~ameyk1/CummingsSNUG1998SJ_FSM.pdf) is also a good source for more info.

**EDIT**: As @Greg pointed out, it was a copy-paste error. A combinational block must use **blocking assignments**.

Comment: So very close, but the code snippet is wrong. Look at the examples given is the links provided. Also, blocking assignments should be used in combinational blocks.

Comment: It was a copy-paste error. Corrected. Thanks for pointing out @Greg.

Comment: @shrvil111 , the conditions of the case statement were still incorrect, so I took the liberty of correcting it.

Comment: @Greg Thanks again! I never looked in the internal code, the intent was just to elaborate usage of FSM encoding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: thank you and @Greg ! What are some good resources/textbooks to learn more about verilog that you recommend?